# Footnotes before the end of the page in reledpar

Tags: footnotes, minipage, reledpar, parallel-texts

I have to make separate footnotes for each column of the text (Russian–English translation). The main text can contain some mini-pages (in order to make framed text). However, I confronted two problems in the presented part of the text:

1. It seems to me that this mini-page environment somehow makes LaTeX think that this is the end of the page and it's time to put a footnote
2. The line that should separate a footnote and main text body is placed in the left column.

I and very new in LaTeX (basically, this is my first try there) and I only use Overleaf. I know, there are some issues with reledpar package there because it's not the newest version there but I only can use Overleaf for now.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian, french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}        

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\setgoalfraction{0.8}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}   
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{russian}
            \beginnumbering
\pstart
На правой воротине сверху висела ржавая жестяная табличка: «Ул. Лукоморье, д. No.13, Н. К. Горыныч», а под нею красовался кусок фанеры с надписью чернилами вкривь и вкось:
\pend
\pstart
\begin{Center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\centering
КОТ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
\newline
Администрация
\end{minipage}}
\end{Center}
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
– Какой КОТ? – спросил я. – Комитет Оборонной Техники?
\pend
\pstart
Бородатый хихикнул.
\pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{english}
     \beginnumbering
   \pstart
\begin{ledgroup}
On the right wing hung a rusty sheet-metal tablet reading, Lukomoriye St., No. 13, N.K. Gorynitch,\footnoteB{Reference to Zmei Gorynitch, a fire-breathing dragon of Russian folklore} while under it, in shameless splendor, a piece of plywood bore in inked letters leaning every which way:
\end{ledgroup}
\pend
\pstart
\begin{Center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\centering
CAT OUT OF ORDER
\newline
Administration
\end{minipage}}
\end{Center}
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
“What CAT?” I asked. “Committee for Advanced Technology?”
\pend
\pstart
The bearded one tittered. 
\pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use a normal `\footnote` and not `\footnoteB` you could replace your command with `\footnotemark` at the place it appears (`\footnotemark[<number>]` if you need more footnotes in this page) and then add a `footnotetext{<Footnote content>}` (or `footnotetext[<number>]{...}`) somewhere in the real text of the page (when you are not inside a minipage). This is the way LaTeX works in general with footnotes and Overleaf has nothing to do with this question.... Except if `\footnoteB` is provided from a package that it's 2016 version is outdated and now has different features than then.

Comment: @koleygr Thanks for an option. I have to know where my page will end for this, right? It is a tricky question as I am not sure about final font and everything else so it might easily change during the book preparation, many times.

Comment: If you place it just at the point that the minipage ends you will be almost 100% sure that it will be printed at the same place that the minipage ends. The difficult part is when this minipage is inside a float... But if not, you are almost sure you will not find problems in the placement because a `\footnote` command rarely is placed in a next page (doesn't really start a new page by it's own but sometimes in special cases of many footnotes it could appear on a next page and this means you should reduce the footnotes and use comments in the actual text instead -at least for me-)

Comment: @koleygr Maybe I was'n clear enough: this is just a part of a big chapter so I actually don't want to specify the exact location of a footnote in the text; it just should be placed in the end of the page (and page break can be in a different places depending on my final margins, fonts and so on).

Comment: May be I was not clear enough too... You can do what I said, just by adding the `\footnotetext` command exactly after the `\end{minipage}`... The minipage will be on page 118 and thus, the footnote's mark will be in the specific minipage of the page 118 and its text will be at the bottom of the page 118. Hope its clear now.

Comment: @koleygr Thanks, it indeed fixed the position. However, now it is placed on the left side of the page (and I need it in the right side, under the English text)

Comment: Please open a different question with your request since it is a completely different question and a really special request that would be better not to be merged (and lost) within this question

Comment: @koleygr actually, this doesn't work as I thought: it puts the footnote not on the same page as a mini page - but at the end of the whole document. So there is at least one more issue.