# Footnotes on the right side of the page with reledpar and minipage

Tags: footnotes, minipage, reledpar, parallel-texts

I need to move the footnote from the right side of the page (reledpar package, this is a quotation from a bilingual book) to the left. The previous solution ([Footnotes before the end of the page in reledpar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478215/footnotes-before-the-end-of-the-page-in-reledpar)) didn't work because of a minipage environment that creates a framed text right after the footnote.

Currently I have this:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian, french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}        

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\setgoalfraction{0.8}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}   
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{russian}
    \beginnumbering
\pstart
На правой воротине сверху висела ржавая жестяная табличка: «Ул. Лукоморье, д. No.13, Н. К. Горыныч», а под нею красовался кусок фанеры с надписью чернилами вкривь и вкось:
\pend
\pstart
\begin{Center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\centering
КОТ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
\newline
Администрация
\end{minipage}}
\end{Center}
\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
– Какой КОТ? – спросил я. – Комитет Оборонной Техники?
\pend
\pstart
Бородатый хихикнул.
\pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{english}
    \beginnumbering
   \pstart
On the right wing hung a rusty sheet-metal tablet reading, Lukomoriye St., No. 13, N.K. Gorynitch,\footnotemark{} while under it, in shameless splendor, a piece of plywood bore in inked letters leaning every which way:
\pend
\pstart
\begin{Center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\centering
CAT OUT OF ORDER
\newline
Administration
\end{minipage}}\footnotetext{Reference to Zmei Gorynitch, a fire-breathing dragon of Russian folklore}
\end{Center}

\pend
\pstart
\pend
\pstart
“What CAT?” I asked. “Committee for Advanced Technology?”
\pend
\pstart
The bearded one tittered. 
\pend
    \endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

which gives me next output:
[image]

Comment: Converting your code to use paracol fixed the footnotes, but had trouble with the line numbering (also \pstart and \pend, whatever they do).

Comment: `\pstart` and `\pend` are the borders of chunks that need to be aligned and I have to keep them.

Comment: Only if you keep using reledpar.  Paracol aligns using \switchcolumn*.